# realloc выдает ошибку в памяти

Tags: c, указатели

```
int i=0, ii=1, j, k, choose=0;
char q='a';
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char));
words[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);

do {
    printf("you want again(0, 1)\n");
    scanf("%d", &choose);
    j = 0; k = 1;
    do {
        fflush(stdin);
        q = getchar();
        *words[j] = q;
        words[j] = (char *)realloc(words[j], (k+1) * sizeof(char));
        j++; k++;
    } while (q != '\n');
    *words[k] = '\0';
    i++; ii++;
    words = (char**)realloc(words ,ii*sizeof(char));
} while (choose);

puts("pRINT");
int d = 0, t = 0;
for (d = 0; d < i; d++) {
    printf("%s\n", words[d]);
}
```

Нужно создать массив строк. Размер массива и размер каждой строки заранее неизвестен. Идея такова что начинаю malloc(sizeof(char)) а потом после добавления каждого слова увеличиваю на один через realloc words. А когда добавляю каждую букву до символа новой строки  заполняется сама строка тоже после каждого символа увеличиваю на один realloc() саму строку `*words[i]`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Данные предложения кода уже некорректные

```
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char));
words[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);
```

В первом предложении вы выделяете под указатель типа `char *` всего лишь один байт `sizeof(char)`. Поэтому в следующем предложении запись адреса выделенной памяти для двух байтов в этот указатель ( `words[0]` ) ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

По крайней мере вам следовало написать

```
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
                                      ^^^^^^
```

Данная запись

```
*words[k] = '\0';
```

также некорректная. Опчть-таки по крайней мере должно быть

```
( *words )[k] = '\0';
```

или более точно

```
words[i][k] = '\0';
```

Правда, трудно разобраться, что из многочисленного объявления переменных, таких как `i`, `ii` и других означает индекс текущей строки. Может быть надо написать

```
words[ii][k] = '\0';
     ^^^
```

Я не знаю.

Но и в этом случае эта запись ошибочная, так как происходит попытка записи за пределы выделенной памяти.

Далее уже не имеет смысла анализировать вашу программу, так как она уже изначально бессмысленная и некорректная.

К C++ ваш код также никакого отношения не имеет. Поэтому я исправил метку вашего вопроса с C++ на C.